# Aurelia bindable Router not working with CLI

Tags: aurelia

I seem to have problem with using `@bindable` and `<nav-bar router.bind="router"></nav-bar>`. I spent some good amount of time trying to find what could be missing but from what I can tell, I all seems to be complete however none of my route shows up. It's completely empty and also looking at the DOM, I can as well see that nothing got populated. This used to work in `WebPack`, so I'm not sure why this wouldn't work in `CLI`.

Also to give a little bit of history, the routes are all showing correctly if I use `<require from="./nav-bar.html"></require>` (that is with `.html`), however I want to add `Aurelia-Auth` to my project and so I do need to add some code in the `nav-bar.js` file. I have almost identical code with `WebPack` and that doesn't seem to fail there, so I'm not sure why `CLI` is not showing anything.

Here's a briefing of my code.

*app.html*

```
<template>
  <require from="./styles/bootstrap.css"></require>
  <require from="./styles/styles.css"></require>
  <require from="./nav-bar"></require>

  <nav-bar router.bind="router"></nav-bar>

  <div class="page-host">
    <loading-indicator loading.bind="router.isNavigating || api.isRequesting"></loading-indicator>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

*app.js*

```
export class App {
  configureRouter(config, router) {
    config.title = 'Aurelia';
    config.map([
      { route: ['', 'welcome'], name: 'home',     moduleId: 'welcome',                nav: true, title: 'Welcome' },
      { route: 'contacts',      name: 'contacts', moduleId: 'modules/contacts/index', nav: true,  title: 'Contacts' },
      { route: 'todo',          name: 'TODO',     moduleId: 'modules/todo/index',     nav: true,  title: 'TODO' }
    ]);

    this.router = router;
  }
}
```

*nav-bar.html*

*(also, as noted in the comments with/without bindable="router"> doesn't make any differences here)*

```
<template bindable="router"> 
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-light bg-faded">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
      <span>${router.title}</span>
    </a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li repeat.for="row of router.navigation" class="nav-item ${row.isActive ? 'active' : ''}">
          <a class="nav-link" data-target="#skeleton-navigation-navbar-collapse.in" href.bind="row.href">${row.title}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
</template>
```

*nav-bar.js*

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {customElement, bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Element)
@customElement('nav-bar')

export class NavBar {
  @bindable router;

  constructor() {
    console.log('navbar constructor');
    console.log(this.router);
  }
}
```

aurelia.json

```
    "transpiler": {
    "id": "babel",
    "displayName": "Babel",
    "fileExtension": ".js",
    "options": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-class-properties",
        "transform-decorators-legacy",
        "transform-es2015-modules-amd"
      ]
    },
    "source": "src\\**\\*.js"
  },
  ...
  "dependencies": [
              "aurelia-binding",
              "aurelia-bootstrapper",
              "aurelia-dependency-injection",
              "aurelia-event-aggregator",
              "aurelia-fetch-client",
              "aurelia-framework",
              "aurelia-history",
              "aurelia-history-browser",
              "aurelia-http-client",
              "aurelia-loader",
              "aurelia-loader-default",
              "aurelia-logging",
              "aurelia-logging-console",
              "aurelia-metadata",
              "aurelia-pal",
              "aurelia-pal-browser",
              "aurelia-path",
              "aurelia-polyfills",
              "aurelia-route-recognizer",
              "aurelia-router",
              "aurelia-task-queue",
              "aurelia-templating",
              "aurelia-templating-binding"
    ]
```

If anyone wants to see the full picture, and/or download or test the code, I have a public repo available on [Github](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Realtime-TODO-Aurelia-RethinkDB/tree/master/client-cli/src) which contain both packages, that is `CLI` and `WebPack`.

Also note that I updated all packages to latest available versions (that include Babel, Aurelia-CLI and the rest).

Comment: You don't need the bindable="router" on the template tag because you have it defined in your viewmodel. Not sure if that's the cause though.

Comment: Yeah I did try to remove it, it has no effect though :(

Answer (score 0):

After restarting from scratch and piece by piece, with still the `Aurelia-App-Contact` as the base repo. I finally found the problem, which in my case, was related to 2 issues. First I was missing a `.babelrc` config file and second because I was missing that file, I had found on `Babel` website that I need 2 plugins to make use of decorators (like `@inject`) and I manually inserted them in my `aurelia.json` config, however these were not directly compatible.

The content of the missing `.babelrc` is

```
{
  "sourceMap": true,
  "moduleIds": false,
  "comments": false,
  "compact": false,
  "code": true,
  "presets": [ "es2015-loose", "stage-1"],
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-flow",
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-flow-strip-types"
  ]
}
```

Then my main problem was caused by adding two `Babel` plugins to the `aurelia.json` config file. Those of which were not totally compatible with `Aurelia`, hence the `.babelrc` is there for for that reason.

```
"plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties", // CAUSE OF THE ISSUE
    "transform-decorators-legacy", // CAUSE OF THE ISSUE
    "transform-es2015-modules-amd"
]
```

The result of the `Babel` plugin inside `aurelia.json` should be this

```
"transpiler": {
    "id": "babel",
    "displayName": "Babel",
    "fileExtension": ".js",
    "options": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-es2015-modules-amd"
      ]
    },
    "source": "src/**/*.js"
  },
```

Also as pointed out by @mgiesa, I should remove the `bindable="router"` from my template. That is replace this `<template bindable="router">` to this `<template>`